# CoreData tips for good implementation

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, core-data

Our app uses CoreData a lot for processing and using data in our app. 
Now i want to make this process more stable. The issues with our system started with iOS 7 and seems to be more extensive on iOS 8. So im looking to do some refactoring. We have a lot of users and i use a BugTracker for analytics on crashes. Im seeing these ones a lot because of our use of CoreData:

```
Object's persistent store is not reachable from this NSManagedObjectContext's coordinator 
---
Attempt to allocate 1048576 bytes for NS/CFData failed
---
SIGSEGV
```

Im using CoreData with a CoreDataController like Apple proposed on their examples. With 2 managed object context for background and main.

This is initiated by a SharedInstance controller..

Is there any framework or page with a more crash prove CoreData example. So to be clear, its working our system for 100.000+ users, but the most crashes (15%) of all users impacted are experiencing crashes with CoreData operations. So how can i eliminate them the best?

Comment: Just guessing, are you storing big file in your CoreData? If so, avoid to do so, instead, store big file in local file system, save the fileURL in CoreData then.

Answer (score 0):

As you probably already know CoreData is not threadsafe per se. So if you are working with your database on different threads you probably need to take more care of your database stack.
In personal experience I think a 3-layer core data stack is more appropriate for a large scale app. (see: http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/07/multi-context-coredata/ , http://floriankugler.com/blog/2013/4/2/the-concurrent-core-data-stack).

With that architecture you can almost be sure that nothing very horrible happens to your managed object contexts.

Also it may help to have a class that performs save on each table you have with a different child managed object context. This way your saves and fetches never intercept with each other.